# Flutter Firebase Matching user data

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to match different users based on their saved Musics. I have a collection called user Data with one documment for every User. In each User document, there is a music collection with one document per Music.

Here is the code I've tried :

```
  class FindFriendsWithSameMusicTastesMatchPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    String _uid = user.uid;
    String _id = "";
    Query _postRef = Firestore.instance.collection('User Data/$_uid/Music');
    Query _userRef = Firestore.instance.collection('User Data');
    Query _userSongRef = Firestore.instance.collection('User Data/$_id/Music');
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _postRef.snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            List<String> _list = [];
            snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {
              _list.add(element.documentID);
            });
            return StreamBuilder(
                stream: _userRef.snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
                    snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {
                      _id = element['uid'];
                      return StreamBuilder(
                          stream: _userSongRef.snapshots(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {
                              snapshot.data.documents.forEach((elementBis) {
                                print(elementBis.documentID);
                                if (elementBis.documentID == _list[i]) {
                                  print(_id);
                                  return Container();
                                } else {
                                  return Container();
                                }
                              });
                            }
                            return Container();
                          });
                    });
                  }
                  return Container();
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I would gladly accept help from anyone. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide data structures to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please rephrase the question properly to mention your issue. Also using three streambuilders  here for the purpose matching users listening to same data is a bit overworked.

Instead u can just keep a separate music collection where you store a list of uid of users listening to each music document. Combine this with firestore array query to fetch only those records which have your uid stored.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely better and plus, it works! Thank you !